# Adicionar classes a um software em tempo de execução

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, reflexão

**Pergunta**

> Há algum recurso que alguma linguagem disponibiliza para poder-se adicionar em tempo de execução uma classe ao software em execução, ou seja, o software a reconhecer e assim poder instanciar objetos dessa classe e manipulá-los?

**Imaginemos a seguinte situação:**
Tomemos com exemplo a linguagem **Java**. Temos essa classe abstrata disponibilizada como esqueleto para que os usuários possam implementar:

```
public abstract class TypeGeneral {

    MyAttribute my_atr;   // um objeto qualquer que toda implementação
                          // de TypeGeneral tem que ter
    public General(MyAttribute e) {
         my_atr = e;
    }

    public abstract void run();    // <==

    public MyAttribute getAttr() { /*...*/ }
    public MyAttribute setAttr(MyAttribute e) { /*...*/ }

    // ...
}
```

Eu queria saber se há algum recurso que dê a possibilidade que, após o usuário fazer a sua classe estendendo a `TypeGeneral`, e assim implementando o método `run()`, possa, em tempo de execução, adicioná-la ao sistema que está executando, e o sistema, reconhecendo-a, faça manipulações com o objetos da mesma.

Vi algo sobre `Reflection`, mas não soube adaptar ao meu  problema. Alguém se dispõe?

**Linguagens preferenciais**

- `Java`
- `Python`
- `C#`
- `C++`

Comment: Alguém sugere um título melhor? Não edite, sugira aqui mesmo.

Comment: Isso é altamente dependente da linguagem e do ambiente de execução. Seria interessante restringir mais o seu domínio.

Comment: Sei que tem jeito, mas eu Java eu não sei os detalhes de como fazer.

Comment: Java tem o ClassLoader, veja se te atende: [http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)

Comment: Em qual linguagem você sabe @bigown? Pode ser em uma das outras 3 que citei... Vou olhar aqui @Piovezan

Comment: A pergunta tem a *tag* [tag:java], até para não ficar ampla.

Comment: Por exemplo em um ambiente Web @Pablo Almeida, com alguma dessas linguagens, onde o servidor receberia de cada usuário suas implementações e retornasse para cada um a funcionalidade adicionada pela sua implementação.

Comment: Eu coloquei ``java`` por conta do exemplo que apresento @bigown kk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é muito comum em Java. Os drivers JDBC, por exemplo, são carregados na memória por meio desse tipo de mecanismo. Isso é útil nas situações onde não é possível saber *a priori* (em tempo de desenvolvimento) a classe que será instanciada.

Um pequeno exemplo. Suponha que exista a seguinte classe em seus sistema:

```
package com.company;

class TesteClasseDinamica {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Suponha agora que você esteja em outra classe e queira instanciar um objeto da classe `com.company.TesteClasseDinamica` de maneira dinâmica:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Class clazz = Class.forName("com.company.TesteClasseDinamica");

    TesteClasseDinamica t = (TesteClasseDinamica) clazz.newInstance();
    t.x = 2;
    t.y = 3;

    System.out.print(t.x);
    System.out.print(t.y);
}
```

Note que, nesse cenário, para instanciar um objeto da classe `TesteClasseDinamica` utiliza-se o método `newInstance()` da classe `Class`.

Isso é muito importante em JDBC, pois a interface precisa ser genérica, de forma a atender qualquer banco de dados relacional. Como não é possível prever qual será a implementação (driver JDBC) utilizado pela aplicação, utiliza-se esse mecanismo para instanciar o driver de forma dinâmica.